# formatTime with "h" instead of ":" as separator

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, fullcalendar

We use the following 24 hour format for time in Portugal: `18h30`.
I've tried:

```
timeFormat: 'H'h'(mm)'
timeFormat: {'H'h'(mm)'}
timeFormat: 'H\h(mm)'
```

Is it possible?
Thank you.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? This isn't jQuery core, is it?

Comment: @KarlsFriend: The tag `fullcalendar` looks like a strong hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single quotes *inside* the javascript string to insert the letter `h` as literal text. The easiest way for this is to use double quotes as string delimiters, as in:

```
timeFormat: "H'h'(mm)"
```

For reference, if you want to use single quotes inside a single quoted string, use an escape for each quote, as in:

```
timeFormat: 'H\'h\'(mm)'
```

Answer (score 1):

An up-to-date solution is reported here and works for FullCalendar2: [formatTime with “h” instead of “:” as separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127435/formattime-with-h-instead-of-as-separator/28154399#28154399)

**Escaping Characters:**

To escape characters in format strings, you can wrap the characters in square brackets.

```
moment().format('[today] dddd'); // 'today Sunday'
```

This works for the formatTime fullcalendar option too:

```
timeFormat: 'H[h](mm)'
```