# formatTime with “h” instead of “:” as separator

Tags: fullcalendar

In France, we use the following 24 hour format for time: 18h30.

Therefore, I want to add the "h" char in the timeFormat option of FullCalendar 2.
I found an older post here:
[formatTime with "h" instead of ":" as separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176338/formattime-with-h-instead-of-as-separator)
but the solution is apparently not working anymore with FullCalendar v2.

Is there a way I could "escape" the "h" character in the timeFormat option ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fullcalendar uses [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs) for date/times.

[Escaping Characters:](http://momentjs.com/docs/#escaping-characters)

> To escape characters in format strings, you can wrap the characters in
>   square brackets.
>
> `moment().format('[today] dddd'); // 'today Sunday'`

This works for the `formatTime` fullcalendar option too:

```
timeFormat: 'H[h](mm)'
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/40yx8j4e/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot escape it, however you can use the `eventRender` method to do the trick for you.

When the event is being rendered parse the DOM and replace the occurrence of : with h.

```
            timeFormat: "H:mm",
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.find('.fc-time').text(function () {
                    return $(this).text().replace(":", "h"); 
                });
            }
```

Comment: Sure you can escape, it uses momentjs.